# How to append dataframes inside a for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to append the DataFrame in the four loop, for loop works fine, however it is not appending the data frames, any help would be much appreciated.

```
   symbols = ['MSFT', 'GOOGL', 'AAPL']
   apikey = 'CR*****YDA'
   for s in symbols:
     print(s)
     url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=%s&apikey=%s"  % (s, apikey)
     stockdata = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
     data = stockdata.read().decode()
     js = json.loads(data)
     a = pd.DataFrame(js['Time Series (Daily)']).T
     b = pd.DataFrame()
     print(b)
     b = b.append(a, ignore_index=True)
     print(b)
     print("loop successful")

print("run successfull")
```

Outputs:

```
MSFT
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
     1. open   2. high    3. low  4. close  5. volume
0   107.4600  107.9000  105.9100  107.7100   37427587
1   105.0000  106.6250  104.7600  106.1200   28393015
..       ...       ...       ...       ...        ...
99  109.2700  109.6400  108.5100  109.6000   19662331

[100 rows x 5 columns]
loop successful
GOOGL
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
      1. open    2. high     3. low   4. close 5. volume
0   1108.5900  1118.0000  1099.2800  1107.3000   2244569
1   1087.9900  1100.7000  1083.2600  1099.1200   1244801
..        ...        ...        ...        ...       ...
99  1244.1400  1257.8700  1240.6800  1256.2700   1428992

[100 rows x 5 columns]
loop successful
AAPL
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
     1. open   2. high    3. low  4. close 5. volume
0   157.5000  157.8800  155.9806  156.8200  33751023
1   154.2000  157.6600  153.2600  155.8600  29821160
..       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
99  217.1500  218.7400  216.3300  217.9400  20525117

[100 rows x 5 columns]
loop successful
run successfull
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you kept erasing the value of b with an empty DataFrame. So you have to define b as a DataFrame before the for loop.

```
symbols = ['MSFT', 'GOOGL', 'AAPL']
apikey = 'CR*****YDA'
b = pd.DataFrame()
for s in symbols:
  print(s)
  url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=%s&apikey=%s"  % (s, apikey)
  stockdata = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  data = stockdata.read().decode()
  js = json.loads(data)
  a = pd.DataFrame(js['Time Series (Daily)']).T
  print(b)
  b = b.append(a, ignore_index=True)
  print(b)
  print("loop successful")

print("run successfull")
```

Answer (score 2):

The *immediate* problem is you define `b` as an empty dataframe *within* each iteration of your `for` loop. Instead, define it once before your `for` loop begins:

```
b = pd.DataFrame()
for s in symbols:
    # some code
    a = pd.DataFrame(js['Time Series (Daily)']).T
    b = b.append(a, ignore_index=True)
```

But appending dataframes in a loop is *not* recommended. It requires unnecessary copy operations and is inefficient. The docs [recommend](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html) on an iterable of dataframes:

```
list_of_dfs = []
for s in symbols:
    # some code
    list_of_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(js['Time Series (Daily)']).T)

b = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the following code

```
b = pd.DataFrame()
```

to outside of the loop would fix your problem. Right now, 'b' is re-initialized as empty dataframe every loop.